# Python mysql connector implicitly converts string to integers

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am having a mysql table with the following schema and table.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
USE test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test_table (
    _id_pn INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    _element TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (_id_pn)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I am using mysql python connector to connect to the database and execute queries as follows.

```
import mysql.connector

MYSQL_CONFIG = {
    'autocommit': True,
    'ssl_disabled': True,
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': 3307,
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'toor',
    'pool_size': 1,
    'database': 'test'
}

def insert_into_table(cursor, element):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (_element) values (%s)", (element,))

def print_table_values(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT _element from test_table")
    for row in cursor:
        print(row['_element'])
        print(type(row['_element']))

def print_table_values_raw_cursor(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT _element from test_table")
    for (elem,) in cursor:
        decoded_elem = elem.decode('utf-8')
        print(decoded_elem)
        print(type(decoded_elem))

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**MYSQL_CONFIG)
cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)
insert_into_table(cursor, "000001")
print_table_values(cursor)

cursor2 = cnx.cursor(buffered=True, raw=True)
print_table_values_raw_cursor(cursor2)

cursor.close()
cursor2.close()
cnx.close()
```

The result of running this code is.

```
1
<type 'int'>
000001
<type 'unicode'>
```

Can anyone explain the reason why code behaves this way?
Also, is using raw cursor and manually decoding values a good idea?

Python version=2.7.10

Python mysql connector version=8.0.16

Mysql server version= 5.6.44-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)